# How to point Flutter Google_Sign_in package to local Firebase emulator?

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication, google-signin, firebase-tools

In Flutter **Web**, I can configure my app to connect to my local emulator and optionally create some fake accounts for my testing: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/flutter/federated-auth#google

```dart
await Firebase.initializeApp(options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform);
await FirebaseAuth.instance.useAuthEmulator('localhost', 9099);
GoogleAuthProvider googleProvider = GoogleAuthProvider();
await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithRedirect(googleProvider);
```

[image]

However, when I do that same for **Mobile**, it always goes to the Google server for authentication, even though I can use the result to sign in to the local Emulator afterwards.

```dart
// Trigger the authentication flow
final GoogleSignInAccount? googleUser = await GoogleSignIn().signIn();

// Obtain the auth details from the request
final GoogleSignInAuthentication? googleAuth = await googleUser?.authentication;

// Create a new credential
final credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(accessToken: googleAuth?.accessToken, idToken: googleAuth?.idToken,);

// This following line connects to the local emulator
await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCredential(credential);
```

**Question:** How can I make the Mobile connecting to local emulator the same way as it does for the Web - doesn't need go to Google Server for authentication a user and can rely on local emulator for fake accounts?